# Is there any way to check a string for additional characters?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is there any way to `check` a string for `additional characters`?

```
[buffer rangeOfString:@"\n"]
```

I get an `input string` and need to check if it contains `any additional character like [{}“¶`
Is it possible to check this with one command? Is there a way like in java to do this? If one character is wrong in the whole buffer i need to do something.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < buffer.lenght;i++){
    if(buffer[i] < Z && buffer[i] >a){
       do something cool...
    }
    else System.exit();
}
```

this code is not correct just to show up what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "additional characters" but if you mean punctuation, you can do something like:

```
if ([buffer rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationChracterSet]].location != NSNotFound)
```

Or if you mean "non letter" you can say:

```
if ([buffer rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
```

Comment: ty this is what i wanted to know :)